# getJSON and parseJSON issue in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

i want to traverse my json but i am getting issue.
here is json which my file returns me and my code

Code

```
var json=null;
$.getJSON("ajax_files/getmyjson.php?id="+id, function(json){ 
   json = json[0];
```

alert(json.id);//this is ok,id=15

here is issue

```
var getReq = jQuery.parseJSON('['+json.property_req_1+']');
$.each(getReq, function(id, key) {
alert(id+'='+key);//not working
});
});
```

JSON

```
[{"id":"15",
"rand_key":"1234",
"landlord_name":"Shah",
"property_req_1":{
"lead_req_id":"",
"lead_id":"0",
"category_id":"1",
"region_id":"1",
"area_location_id":"17",
"sub_area_location_id":"3447",
"min_beds":"1",
"max_beds":"",
"min_budget":"3332",
"max_budget":"0",
"min_area":"",
"max_area":"0",
"unit_type":"2",
"unit_no":"",
"listing_id_1_ref":"RH-R-17",
"listing_id_1":"17"
}
}]
```

Comment: if you see here is another json "property_req_1":{,so double curly is for that

Comment: You should use classing javascript for iterating through an array: `for(var i = 0; i < getReq.length; i++) { var item = getReq[i]; // console.log(item); } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse JSON again. Try this:

```
$.each(json.property_req_1, function(id, key) {
    alert(id+'='+key);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `'['+json.property_req_1+']'` would evaluate to `'[[object Object]]'` which is an invalid JSON notation.

If you want to iterate over `json.property_req_1`'s properties (which is already a valid object), you can simply do:

```
$.each(json.property_req_1, function(id, key) {
    console.log(id + '=' + key);
}
```

Comment: how to get specific item?can i do like this?  this.category_id

Comment: A specific item would be done via `json.property_req_1.category_id` @user2244804

Answer (score -1):

```
$.each(json.property_req_1, function(key, value) { alert(key + "=" + value); });
```